# Where can I find the solutions manual to Beginning Statistics with Data Analysis by Mosteller, Fienberg and Rourke?

Tags: reference-request, statistics

I am planning to teach a course on Statistics using [Beginning Statistics with Data Analysis by Mosteller, Fienberg and Rourke](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486492710.html). On page xii of the book, the authors said "A solutions manual is available to the instructor ... ". May I know where I can purchase/request/download this solution manual? My search for this solution manual was unsuccessful.

Comment: It seems that the original version of the book by Addison-Wesley is out of print.  (It was last published in 1983.)  I suspect you won't be able to get a solutions manual from the (original) publisher.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche, that's why I am asking here. I was also hoping to contact one of the authors directly, but Mosteller and Fienberg are no longer alive, and I am not sure how to reach Rourke.